# Where to store media files of Django app in order to save them after docker container updating?

Tags: django, docker, file, media

I have a Django app where media files are uploading to the my_project_directory/media/images/ (so nothing special, just a common approach).
The problem raised after dockerizing my app.
Every time i need to update my container after pulling latest docker image, old container is removed(including, of course media files) and the new, empty one is built.
So the question is - how to make my Django app stateless and where/how to store media files?
Is it possible to store them in a special docker container? If yes, how? if no, what could you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use docker `volumes` to mount your persistent data outside of the container.
More info can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: @BengurHayrapetyan did it answer your question?

Comment: yeap, sorry for being super late, have not seen your comment