# Passing Django ContentFile to an ImageField doesn't create an image file on the disk on Docker

Tags: django, docker

The code below works on local when I don't use Docker containers. But when I try to run the same code/project in Docker, while everything else is working great, the part of the code below doesn't work as expected and doesn't save the ContentFile as image file to the disk. The ImageField returns the path of the image but actually it doesn't exist.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

...
photo_as_bytearray = photo_file.get_as_bytearray()  # returns bytearray
cf = ContentFile(photo_as_bytearray)
obj.photo.save('mynewfile.jpg', cf)  # <<< doesn't create the file only on Docker
```

Not sure if there's something I need to change for Docker.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the exact image path that is returned is?

Comment: probably, what you're looking for is docker volumes https://stackoverflow.com/a/65507275/11544538

Comment: @ErsainD. yes, almost. After one hour posting this, I figured out the origin of the problem while trying to sleep, and will post an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the origin of the problem was my Celery worker. It was using the same image of my web container, but...

While my web container has a volume associated with the web folder (./web:/path/to/app) to support hot reloading in development environment, the celery worker was not using this volume. I thought that using the same image (mywebimage:dev) for both would be enough but was not.

So now I'll edit my docker-compose file to make them both use the same (real same) files. Celery was using a copy of the web directory because of the COPY statement in the Dockerfile, not the actual directory I work on and edit. So when the celery worker created a file, it wasn't being created on the volume which has the actual web directory.

Hope that helps someone made the same mistake I did.